# When do changes to a rails association get propagated to parent record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a pair of rails (4) models, *agenda* and *agenda_items* such that an *agenda* has_many *agenda_items* and an *agenda_item* belongs_to *agenda*.  Very straight forward.

An *agenda_item* has two columns: *position* (the index) and *description*.

I need to exchange two *agenda_items* so I interchange the two positions (in the *agenda_item* model) and save! the two records.  When I inspect the two records, the *position* s have been updated accordingly.

Immediately after the exchange (still within the model) I log the *agenda*.*agenda_items* only to find that the change has **not** taken place. A partial rendering of *agenda_items* also does not change.

When I refresh the page, I find that the change **has** taken place.  I have tried putting the exchange in a transaction (to no avail). I have hacked a sleep statement between the exchange and the logging.  After the exchange (but within the sleep period), I can see that it has been done correctly in pgAdmin III.

I tried `Agenda(Item).connection.commit_db_transaction`, but both give me a warning that no transactions are active.

I have tried this in postgresql and sqlite3, both of which show the same symptoms.

Similar code worked in Rails 2, but I haven't used it in 3 or 4 until now.

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The model code (with many hacks still in it) is:

```
def exchange( up )
  delta = up ? -1 : 1
  for item in self.agenda.agenda_items
    Zlogger.debug "before exchange: item #{item.position}:  #{item.description}"
  end
  Zlogger.debug "delta: #{delta}"
  target = self.agenda.agenda_items.where(['position = ?',self.position + delta]).first
  Zlogger.debug "exchanging #{self.position} #{self.description} #{target.position} #{target.description}"  
  p = self.position
  # moving the target to position 0, later moving it to its destination
  # is a hack to make sure that the moves are committed immediately (doesn't always work)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    target.position = 0
    target.save!
    self.position = self.position + delta
    self.save!
    target.position = p
    target.save!
    self.agenda.save!
  end
  Zlogger.debug "exchanged #{self.position} #{self.description} #{target.position} #{target.description}"
  sleep 30.0
  for item in self.agenda.agenda_items
    Zlogger.debug "after exchange: item #{item.position}:  #{item.description}"
  end
end
```

Typical results from Zlogger:

```
before exchange: item 1:  Treasurer''s Report
before exchange: item 2:  Approval of Last Month''s Minutes
before exchange: item 3:  Permanent Layout Report
before exchange: item 4:  Sectional Layout Report
before exchange: item 5:  HO Layout Report
before exchange: item 6:  Operating Committee Report
before exchange: item 7:  Membership Promotion and Engagement
before exchange: item 8:  New Business
before exchange: item 9:  Adjournment
delta: 1
*** Note that the exchange does take place ***
exchanging 1 Treasurer''s Report 2 Approval of Last Month''s Minutes
exchanged 2 Treasurer''s Report 1 Approval of Last Month''s Minutes
*** Note that the exchange has not propagated to the association ***
after exchange: item 1:  Treasurer''s Report
after exchange: item 2:  Approval of Last Month''s Minutes
after exchange: item 3:  Permanent Layout Report
after exchange: item 4:  Sectional Layout Report
after exchange: item 5:  HO Layout Report
after exchange: item 6:  Operating Committee Report
after exchange: item 7:  Membership Promotion and Engagement
after exchange: item 8:  New Business
after exchange: item 9:  Adjournment
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!  I kept digging and after a long google session I discovered that rails will cache an active record association.  When I changed the contents of the associated items I would have thought that the cache would be invalidated so the next reference to the association would get the new values, but it is NOT.

There are two possible methods to use to fix this:

`reset` -> reloads the association if it has changed. **According to the rails documentation, this is the preferred method - but it doesn't work!**

or

`reload` -> forces the association to reload even if the reload isn't needed. **This works!**

In my case, since the contents of the association are known to have been changed by the immediately preceeding statements, `reload` is guaranteed to be needed so `reset` is somewhat redundant.

The code, after all of the debugging and hacks have been removed is simple:

```
def exchange( up )
  delta = up ? -1 : 1
  target = self.agenda.agenda_items.where(['position = ?',self.position + delta]).first
  target.position = self.position
  self.position = self.position + delta
  target.save!
  self.save!
  self.agenda.agenda_items.reload # makes agenda_items consistent with updated contents.
end
```

I don't know if this is a bug in rails, but as I said in my question, I used similar code in Rails 2 that worked - but without needing either the `reset` or `reload` IIRC. Also the rails documentation implies that `reset` should detect the fact that the contents have been modified and call `reload` only when needed.